# Error "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation" in IE11 when downloading large files

Tags: download, internet-explorer-11, httpresponse

When trying to download a large file in IE11, I am getting the error

```
Not enough storage is available to complete this operation
```

This works as expected in Google Chrome.

I have the following code in JS

```
      var byteStr = event.target.response;
      var byteArray = byteStr.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(','); //error occurs at this line
      var fileName = event.target.getResponseHeader('filename');
      var uint8_array = new Uint8Array(byteArray);
      var bb = new Blob([uint8_array], {
        type: 'application/octet-stream'
      });
      if (window.navigator['msSaveBlob']) {
        window.navigator['msSaveBlob'](bb, fileName);
      } else {
        this.download(window.URL.createObjectURL(bb), fileName);
      }
```

Is there a way I can modify my code to be able to download large files (file content inside the response) without having to change any of the IE settings manually?

Comment: How big of files?

Comment: The file size is 31 MB

Comment: I think your response is getting copied multiple times. try splitting it into multiple assignments. Like every .replace call is allocating a new array of that size and copying it.

Comment: I tried to make into separate assignments. I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you step through it with a debugger to see when it happens. Or rather which call causes the issue.

Comment: It's the first line itself `var byteStr = event.target.response;`